# Flutter: cant change file in dependency

Tags: flutter, dart, dependencies, edit

All im trying to do, is that in a file documents.dart, there is a function:

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> search(
      Map<String, dynamic> searchParameters) async {
    return await _apicall.get(
      '$_endPoint/search',
      queryParams: searchParameters,
      shouldCacheResult: true,
    );
  }
```

And i want to make an additional function like this:

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> multisearch(
      Map<String, dynamic> searchParameters) async {
    return await _apicall.get(
      '$_endPoint/multi_search',
      queryParams: searchParameters,
      shouldCacheResult: true,
    );
  }
```

Yet for some reason, flutter will not save the additional method to the file when I try to save, and cannot call the method. All it does is say "warning: you are editing a pub cache". Anyone know whats going on?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you are editing the wrong file! What is the path of the file that you are editing? In which folder does it sit?

Comment: I think you've edited some library code. Make sure your source code is in the lib folder and the file you're editing is your file..